# ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined

Tags: next.js, tone.js

I'm trying to use tone.js in a next.js react project.
When I run or build i get this error "ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined"

I have isolated the tone.js code in codesandbox and it's working perfectly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-react-pink-noise-generator-pfnl0?file=/src/App.js

But not in the next.js app

````
ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined
    at ki (/node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js:1:117922)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) is a web browser thing, it does not exist in node.js. The error you are getting is because the code that uses `AudioBuffer` can't run on the server. You need to instantiate that part of the code only in the browser. That is usually done in `useEffect` hook, or on the server, you can first check if `window` object is defined.

Comment: Thanks, I've reworked my example in codesandbox above to instantiate the new Tone.Noise within the useEffect hook and assigned it to state. It's working in my next.js code now :)